# Deactivate NSLayoutConstrain from storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I want to set up a constrain in storyboard but deactivate it in Storyboard 
for a while, until a user interaction happens. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `constraint.active` to `NO`, then set it back to `YES` to re-enable it.

If you want to disable it in the storyboard, go to the Identity inspector([image]), then click the `+` button under the **User Defined Runtime Attributes** header. Double-click the section of the highlighted row that says “keyPath”. Type in `active`, then uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: I done like you wrote, and get this error, when changing priority: 'Mutating a priority from required to not on an installed constraint (or vice-versa) is not supported.  You passed priority 1 and the existing priority was 1000. `'Mutating a priority from required to not on an installed constraint (or vice-versa) is not supported.  You passed priority 1 and the existing priority was 1000.'`

Comment: Try setting the priority to 999 in the storyboard.

Comment: same for 999 priority

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible.**

1. Create an `IBOutlet` for that `NSLayoutConstraint` and connect it your mentioned contraint in `Storyboard`.

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;
   ```

   *myConstraint is a constraint on myView*
2. On `viewDidLoad` write this code: `[_myView removeConstraint:_myConstraint];`
3. Then, when a user interaction happens:  `[_myView addConstraint:_myConstraint];`

Comment: crashes, after deactivation it get nil

Comment: so instead of set `active`, use `add`, `remove`, but keep a strong pointer on it